# NeuPro Language?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I don't have so much a question about how to program something, but rather I'm looking for information on a specific programming language that I can't seem to find anywhere.  It seems to be referenced in a few papers I'm looking at.  The name of the language is "NeuPro" - it would be for working with Neural Networks and appears to have a syntax very similar to prolog.  Anyway, if someone could shed some light of provide a reference I can work on that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a reference to Neural Prolog.

**Neural Prolog-the concepts, construction and mechanism**
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=538347

> This article introduces a Prolog-like
>   inference system based on Neural
>   Logic. A brief introduction of the
>   background of this research is given
>   first. The logical basis, knowledge
>   construction and inference mechanism
>   of Neural Prolog are described

**An integration of Prolog and neural networks to deal with sensibility in logic programs**
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=138740

> Neuro-Prolog, which integrates the
>   Prolog interpreter C-Prolog and the
>   neural network simulator SunNet, is
>   described. By using Neuro-Prolog,
>   users can handle both definite
>   information, such as logical rules,
>   and indefinite information, such as
>   sensibility, concurrently in a single
>   system. In Neuro-Prolog, the definite
>   information is handled in Prolog and
>   the indefinite information is handled
>   in neural networks.

Comment: I had found this - but I'm not sure this is the implementation that is being used.  However based on the fact that this is all I could find - and at least one other person believes this is the best choice I am going to run with it.  Thanks for the help!